# Using AI to get the geographic locations of a list of banks

Tags: machine-learning, geography

I have a list of banks from Bloomberg, and am looking to locate them on the world map,

```
list = {"DZ Bank AG Deutsche Zentral-Genossenschaftsb", "HSBC", "NatWest Markets", "TD Securities", "UniCredit", "BNP Paribas Securities Services/Luxembourg", "Linklaters LLP/Luxembourg", "Sustainalytics BV", "Barclays", "Nomura International PLC"}
```

ChatGPT can for example be asked

> What is the geographic location of DZ Bank AG Deutsche
> Zentral-Genossenschaftsb

and it replies

> DZ Bank AG, also known as Deutsche Zentral-Genossenschaftsbank, is a
> German bank headquartered in Frankfurt. Frankfurt is located in the
> state of Hesse in central Germany.

Can Mathematica's AI plugin's do something similar? So I can get a list of geographic coordinates from the list of banks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Iam looking to locate them on the world map,

Yes. But not on map.

Using the Wolfram language AI command LLMFunction. see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285713/how-to-use-the-new-llmfunction) how to install and use. Ofcourse this plugin just talks to chatGPT on the backend. Only difference is that you can talk to it from inside Mathematica and use the result inside Mathematica, which can be very useful.

```
list={"DZ Bank AG Deutsche Zentral-Genossenschaftsb","HSBC","NatWest Markets","TD Securities","UniCredit","BNP Paribas Securities Services/Luxembourg","Linklaters LLP/Luxembourg","Sustainalytics BV","Barclays","Nomura International PLC"}

LLMFunction["Please give location of these banks. Thank you in advance.``"][list]
```

Gives

```
I'm sorry, but I cannot provide the exact locations of these 
banks as they have multiple branches and offices around the world. 
However, I can provide you with their headquarters or main office 
locations:

- DZ Bank AG Deutsche Zentral-Genossenschaftsb: Frankfurt, Germany
- HSBC: London, United Kingdom
- NatWest Markets: London, United Kingdom
- TD Securities: Toronto, Canada
- UniCredit: Milan, Italy
- BNP Paribas Securities Services/Luxembourg: Luxembourg City, Luxembourg
- Linklaters LLP/Luxembourg: Luxembourg City, Luxembourg
- Sustainalytics BV: Amsterdam, Netherlands
- Barclays: London, United Kingdom
- Nomura International PLC: London, United Kingdom
```

And

```
LLMFunction["What is the geographic location of ``"]["DZ Bank AG Deutsche Zentral-Genossenschaftsb"]

DZ Bank AG Deutsche Zentral-Genossenschaftsbank is headquartered in 
Frankfurt, Germany.
```

> So I can get a list of geographic coordinates from the list of banks?

Yes for this

```
LLMFunction["what is the geographic coordinates of headquarters of these banks? ``"][list]

DZ Bank AG Deutsche Zentral-Genossenschaftsb: 50.1109° N, 8.6821° E (Frankfurt, Germany)
HSBC: 51.5136° N, 0.0891° W (London, United Kingdom)
NatWest Markets: 51.5142° N, 0.0931° W (London, United Kingdom)
TD Securities: 43.6481° N, 79.3819° W (Toronto, Canada)
UniCredit: 45.4642° N, 9.1900° E (Milan, Italy)
BNP Paribas Securities Services/Luxembourg: 49.6116° N, 6.1319° E (Luxembourg City, Luxembourg)
Linklaters LLP/Luxembourg: 49.6116° N, 6.1319° E (Luxembourg City, Luxembourg)
Sustainalytics BV: 52.3702° N, 4.8952° E (Amsterdam, Netherlands)
Barclays: 51.5142° N, 0.0931° W (London, United Kingdom)
Nomura International PLC: 51.5142° N, 0.0931° W (London, United Kingdom)
```

But it does not support maps: May be future AI version could?

```
LLMFunction[  "Please give location of these banks on map. Thank you in advance.``"][list]

I'm sorry, as an AI language model, I don't have the ability 
to provide a map. However, you can easily find the location of 
these banks by searching for them on Google Maps or any other 
mapping service.
```

To use maps, may be use  geographic coordinates generated above and then use that data to generate map. Look at [how-do-i-plot-coordinates-latitude-and-longitude-pairs-on-a-geographic-map](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2076/how-do-i-plot-coordinates-latitude-and-longitude-pairs-on-a-geographic-map)  or similar ones to show them on a map inside Mathematica.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks! Will be using this LLMFunction in the future!